# Using Matcher to extract URL domain name

Tags: java, regex, url

```
    static String AdrPattern="http://www.([^&]+)\\.com\\.*";
    static Pattern WebUrlPattern = Pattern.compile (AdrPattern);
    static Matcher WebUrlMatcher;
                WebUrlMatcher = WebUrlPattern.matcher ("keyword");
                if(WebUrlMatcher.matches())
             String  extractedPath = WebUrlMatcher.group (1);
```

Considering above codes, My aim is to extract the domain name from the URL and dismiss the rest. But the trouble is that, first of all, if the URL has deeper path, it will not ignore it and second, it does not work for all URL with `.com` extension.

For example, if the URL is `http://www.lego.com/en-us/technic/?domainredir=technic.lego`, the result will not be `lego` but `lego.com/en-us/technic/?domainredir=technic.lego`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
static String AdrPattern="http://www\\.([^&]+)\\.com.*";
                                    ^^              ^
```

You escaped the final dot, and it was treated as a literal, and `matches` could not match the entire string. Also, the first dot must be escaped.

Also, to make the regex a bit more strict, you can replace the `[^&]+` with `[^/&]`.

**UPDATE**:

```
static String AdrPattern="http://www\\.([^/&]+)\\.com/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+).*";
static Pattern WebUrlPattern = Pattern.compile (AdrPattern);
static Matcher WebUrlMatcher = WebUrlPattern.matcher("http://www.lego.com/en-us/technic/?domainredir=technic.lego");
if(WebUrlMatcher.matches()) {
    String  extractedPath = WebUrlMatcher.group(1);
    String  extractedPart1 = WebUrlMatcher.group(2);
    String  extractedPart2 = WebUrlMatcher.group(3);
    String  extractedPart3 = WebUrlMatcher.group(4);
}
```

Or, with `\G`:

```
static String AdrPattern="(?:http://www\\.([^/&]+)\\.com/|(?!^)\\G)/?([^/]+)";
static String AdrPattern="http://www\\.([^/&]+)\\.com/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)";
static Pattern WebUrlPattern = Pattern.compile (AdrPattern);
static Matcher WebUrlMatcher = WebUrlPattern.matcher("http://www.lego.com/en-us/technic/?domainredir=technic.lego");
int cnt = 0;
while(WebUrlMatcher.find()) {
    if (cnt == 0) {
       String extractedPath = WebUrlMatcher.group(1);
       String extractedPart = WebUrlMatcher.group(2);
       cnt = cnt + 1;
    }
    else {
       String extractedPart = WebUrlMatcher.group(2);
    }
}
```

Comment: that is right. there is another question you may help. If I want to make each deeper path to be extractable, i should iterate on the `matcher.group(i)`?

Comment: considering the example of the question, `http://www.lego.com/en-us/technic/?domainredir=technic.lego` I want to have access to `technic` or even `?domainredir=technic.lego`

Comment: If you have a fixed number of URL parts and query elements, you can use more capturing groups: [`http://www\\.([^/&]+)\\.com/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/cM0jL9/1) and access them with `.group(2)`, `group(3)`. There is another way to access the unknown number of these URL parts with `\G` operator: [`(?:http://www\\.([^/&]+)\\.com/|(?!^)\\G)/?([^/]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/cM0jL9/2), but it will be more difficult to use as the first match will contain the domain name and the subsequent part, and the following matches will only contain the subparts.

Comment: I dont know, but apparently your regexes are not working.

Comment: It is because you need to use doubled backslashes if you need to match a literal, and you need to use `find` instead of `matches`.

Comment: Should I make an independent question for this case and then you answer it there?

Comment: Please check my update, let me know if it is clear enough. Or if it is what you need. I did not test, but I think it should clear out a lot. When we use the `\G` approach, we have multiple matches, and thus cannot use `matches`, but `find`. I have just added `.*` to the first update, just in case you test against longer URLs.

Comment: That was a perfect answer~ I loved the `\G` operator. However I only have one upvote to use which I already used. anyway, thanks again!

Comment: :) You can always upvote one of [my previous answers for **url** tag](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A3832970+%5Burl%5D). Or [`matcher`](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A3832970+%5Bmatcher%5D).

Comment: oh, so many lovely regex-URL related stuff. Will look into them tomorrow, since it is already past 10pm :)