# Enhancing regex to match more URLs

Tags: java, regex, url

Considering this regex:

```
  static String AdrPattern="(?:http://www\\.([^/&]+)\\.com/|(?!^)\\G)/?([^/]+)";
```

I have two small questions:

1. How is it possible to make it to match URLs that only have the
   domain name, without any further path/segment? (such as
   `https://stackoverflow.com`)
2. How is it possible to make this regex to match URLs with different domain extensions?

**P.S**: the regex is taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32051819/using-matcher-to-extract-url-domain-name) and works fine, but these two shortcomings should be fixed.

**EDIT**

**Based on the below code, the answer made to this post will skip the further segments and only prints the domain name**:

```
         static String AdrPattern= "(?:(?!\\A)\\G(?:/([^\\s/]+))|http://www\\.([^\\s/&]+)\\.(?:com|net|gov|org)(?:/([^\\s/]+))?)";
         static Pattern WebUrlPattern = Pattern.compile (AdrPattern);
         WebUrlMatcher= WebUrlPattern.matcher(line);



        int cn=0;
        while(WebUrlMatcher.find()) {

    if (cnt == 0) 
        {
           String extractedPath = WebUrlMatcher.group(1);

           if(extractedPath!=null){

            fop.write(prefix.toLowerCase().getBytes());


            fop.write(System.getProperty("line.separator").getBytes());



            }

  if(extractedPath!=null)
  {
                fop.write(extractedPath.toLowerCase().getBytes());

                fop.write(System.getProperty("line.separator").getBytes());
  }        

       String extractedPart = WebUrlMatcher.group(2);
       String extractedPart = WebUrlMatcher.group(2);
   String extracted2=WebUrlMatcher.group(3);
   if(extractedPart!=null)
   {
            fop.write(extractedPart.toLowerCase().getBytes());       
            fop.write(System.getProperty("line.separator").getBytes());

            if(extracted2!=null)
            {
            fop.write(extracted2.toLowerCase().getBytes());
            fop.write(System.getProperty("line.separator").getBytes());
            }

   cnt = cnt + 1;

   }
}
    }

    }
```

Comment: Can you include samples of URLs which both should and should not match?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen In a word, I want all the URLs matches but I also want, for those with more paths/segments, it returns them separately. In other words, I want to have access to the segments. as a result, that regex is made but it skips URLs with single path like the shown example. in addition, it only works for a single domain extension at a time. I want these two fixes if possible?

Comment: This is not a word, it is a paragraph, and it still leaves me unsure of exactly what you want.  A picture is worth a thousand words on Stack Overflow.

Comment: So you want it to do both match domain alone _and_ segments when available ?

Comment: @sln exaactly. but this regex does not. Moreover, it should matches more than just a single domain extension at a time.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen how about the `P.S` I made?

Comment: @sln what do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way. A slight manipulation of the current regex.
Just test the capture groups.

```
 "(?:(?!\\A)\\G(?:/([^\\s/]+))|http://www\\.([^\\s/&]+)\\.(?:com|net)(?:/([^\\s/]+))?)"

 (?:
      (?! \A )                      # Not BOS
      \G                            # Start from last match
      (?:
           /  
           ( [^\s/]+ )                   # (1), Required Next Segment path (or fail)
      )
   |                              # or,
      http://www\.                  # New match
      ( [^\s/&]+ )                  # (2), Domain
      \.
      (?: com | net )               # Extension
      (?:
           /  
           ( [^\s/]+ )                   # (3), Optional First Segment path
      )?
 )
```

Test capture's -

Input:

```
http://www.asfdasdf.net/  
http://www.asfdasdf.net/first  
http://www.asfdasdf.net/first/second
```

Output:

```
 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 0 , len 23 ) 
http://www.asfdasdf.net  
 **  Grp 1 -  NULL 
 **  Grp 2 -  ( pos 11 , len 8 ) 
asfdasdf  
 **  Grp 3 -  NULL 

-------------

 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 28 , len 29 ) 
http://www.asfdasdf.net/first  
 **  Grp 1 -  NULL 
 **  Grp 2 -  ( pos 39 , len 8 ) 
asfdasdf  
 **  Grp 3 -  ( pos 52 , len 5 ) 
first  

-------------

 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 61 , len 29 ) 
http://www.asfdasdf.net/first  
 **  Grp 1 -  NULL 
 **  Grp 2 -  ( pos 72 , len 8 ) 
asfdasdf  
 **  Grp 3 -  ( pos 85 , len 5 ) 
first  

-------------

 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 90 , len 7 ) 
/second  
 **  Grp 1 -  ( pos 91 , len 6 ) 
second  
 **  Grp 2 -  NULL 
 **  Grp 3 -  NULL
```

Comment: This is not working. it returns NULL. for a URL like `http://www.meddybemps.com/ (the first URL in the list)
`

Comment: or maybe I am doing it wrong? I am using the same method to access the groups as explained [in here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32051819/using-matcher-to-extract-url-domain-name). should that be changed too?

Comment: @lonesome - Updated with a sample input / output for captures. Yes, they've changed. Group 1 is a continuation of next path segment. Group 2 is a new domain (Group 3 will be the first path segment and is optional).

Comment: No no. You got me wrong. I mean, how can I access to the parts? I used the old way that is shown in the link, but it returns NULL.

Comment: The access to the capture groups is the same. The `test` for null is different. (See the _Output_ above). If a match, use if group 2 is not NULL (have a domain) then check group 3 for not NULL (have first segment). Else if group 1 is not NULL, have a _next_ path segment, etc ...

Comment: Also, I guess you could swap the main alternation parts to use domain and first (optional) segment as groups 1 & 2 and the next segment as group 3, etc ...

Comment: Based my EDIT, it skips some URLs and it skips the further segments and only writes the domain name. What seems to be wrong?

Comment: I edited my EDIT. it still gives not the right answer. right now, it only detects until it has 3 segments (together with the domain name) which is not sufficient in many cases. Can you please find out how to fix it?

Comment: Ok, never mind, I fixed it by using both new (yours) and the old one.